# Indexes in Akiban's Persistit

Tags: java, indexing, persist, key-value-store

Any idea on how to define indexes on data stored with [Akiban's Persistit](https://github.com/pbeaman/persistit) key/value store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't first class/API support for secondary indexes in Persistit. That isn't to say you can't create indexes though!

What is an index? In practice, all an index contains is another copy of the data. For example, in a relational database with a `users` table, an index on the `first_name` column would allow efficient look-up by first name. That can be achieved by storing an additional copy of the first name with the primary identifier to create a "link" back to the main row.

Here's an isolated example of that:

```java
import com.persistit.*;
import com.persistit.exception.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class IndexDemo implements AutoCloseable
{
  public static class User implements Serializable
  {
    public int id;
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(int id, String firstName, String lastName) {
      this.id = id;
      this.firstName = firstName;
      this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return String.format("User(%d, %s, %s)", id, firstName, lastName);
    }
  }

  private final Persistit db;

  public IndexDemo() throws PersistitException {
    Configuration c = new Configuration();
    c.getBufferPoolMap().get(16384).setCount(32);
    c.getVolumeList().add(new VolumeSpecification(
      "IndexDemo.vol,create,pageSize:16384,initialPages:5,extensionPages:5,maximumPages:100"
    ));
    this.db = new Persistit(c);
  }

  @Override
  public void close() throws PersistitException {
    db.close();
  }

  public Exchange userEx() throws PersistitException {
    return db.getExchange("IndexDemo", "users", true);
  }

  public Exchange firstNamesEx() throws PersistitException {
    return db.getExchange("IndexDemo", "firstNames", true);
  }

  // Save the user, both primary and secondary firstName index
  public void saveUser(User u) throws PersistitException {
    Exchange ex = userEx();
    // Primary entries: key of ID and value of full User
    ex.getKey().append(u.id);
    ex.getValue().put(u);
    ex.store();
    // First name index: key of (name,ID)
    ex = firstNamesEx();
    ex.append(u.firstName).append(u.id);
    ex.store();
  }

  // Look-up the user by ID
  public User userByID(int id) throws PersistitException {
    Exchange ex = userEx();
    // Construct and fetch our key
    ex.getKey().append(id);
    ex.fetch();
    // Careful: may not exist
    if(!ex.getValue().isDefined()) {
        return null;
    }
    // Otherwise get it from the value
    return (User)ex.getValue().get();
  }

  // Index scan for users with firstName, look-up and return all matches
  public List<User> usersByFirstName(String firstName) throws PersistitException {
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
    Exchange ex = firstNamesEx();
    // Iterate over only entires matching firstName
    ex.append(firstName).append(Key.BEFORE);
    while(ex.next()) {
      // Index to second component (id) and decode
      int id = ex.getKey().indexTo(1).decodeInt();
      // And lookup the user
      users.add(userByID(id));
    }
    return users;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws PersistitException {
    try(final IndexDemo demo = new IndexDemo()) {
      System.out.println("No Transaction:");
      runDemo(demo);
    }
    try(final IndexDemo demo = new IndexDemo()) {
      System.out.println("Transaction:");
      demo.db.getTransaction().run(new TransactionRunnable() {
        @Override
        public void runTransaction() throws PersistitException {
          runDemo(demo);
        }
      });
    }
  }

  public static void runDemo(IndexDemo demo) throws PersistitException {
    demo.saveUser(new User(1, "John", "Doe"));
    demo.saveUser(new User(2, "John", "Smith"));
    demo.saveUser(new User(3, "Sally", "Jones"));
    System.out.println("  User  1: " + demo.userByID(1));
    System.out.println("  User 10: " + demo.userByID(10));
    System.out.println("  Users named John:");
    for(User u : demo.usersByFirstName("John")) {
      System.out.println("    " + u);
    }
  }
}
```

Running yields this output:

```
No Transaction:
  User  1: User(1, John, Doe)
  User 10: null
  Users named John:
    User(1, John, Doe)
    User(2, John, Smith)
Transaction:
  User  1: User(1, John, Doe)
  User 10: null
  Users named John:
    User(1, John, Doe)
    User(2, John, Smith)
```

There isn't too much going on:

- User POJO with a few attributes
- Basic Persistit configuration and start-up
- Helpers for saving, look-up by primary/ID and scan by first name
- Demo usage of all the helpers
- Main runs the demo both inside and outside of a transaction

All the pieces are there for building something extremely simple, like this demo, to something very sophisticated, like a complete SQL server.

Comment: wonder if this has performance impact as the index is updated at the same time an entry is updated. would it be better for the case of transactions to update the index only when everything is successfully committed? how then?

Comment: Each index does have a cost (i.e. more work during writes/updates) to be weighed against the benefits (i.e. ordering, searching and index-only scans during reads).

As far as delaying the index maintenance, probably not worth it. One of the main benefits of transactions is being able to rely on all the "work" being packaged together.